# Sharing portions of graph in genealogytree

Tags: genealogytree

How can I reuse a portion of a graph between two different `genealogytree` instances? Here is a simplified example of code that just uses manual duplication, but I would like to extract out the graph in the second one to a command or similar to use as part of the first tree.

```latex
\documentclass{letter}
\usepackage[all]{genealogytree}
\begin{document}
  \begin{autosizetikzpicture}{\linewidth}{}
    \genealogytree[]{
      parent{
        g{Child A}
        parent{
          g{Parent A}
          p{Grandparent A}
          p{Grandparent B}
        }
        parent{
          g{Parent B}
          p{Grandparent C}
          p{Grandparent D}
        }
      }
    }
  \end{autosizetikzpicture}
  \begin{autosizetikzpicture}{\linewidth}{}
    \genealogytree[]{
      parent{
        g{Parent A}
        p{Grandparent A}
        p{Grandparent B}
      }
    }
  \end{autosizetikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I tried defining the second tree inside a `newcommand*` but then get `Package genealogytree Error: Parser: unfeasible token.` when I try to use it.

Answer (score 2):

I think I found a solution using the `insert` control sequence documented in §4.10  Control Sequence 'insert' (p. 75) of [the manual](http://ctan.mirrors.hoobly.com/macros/latex/contrib/genealogytree/genealogytree.pdf):

```latex
\documentclass{letter}
\usepackage[all]{genealogytree}
\begin{document}
  \newcommand*{\secondTree}{%
    parent{
      g{Parent A}
      p{Grandparent A}
      p{Grandparent B}
    }
  }
  \begin{autosizetikzpicture}{\linewidth}{}
    \genealogytree[]{
      parent{
        g{Child A}
        insert{secondTree}
        parent{
          g{Parent B}
          p{Grandparent C}
          p{Grandparent D}
        }
      }
    }
  \end{autosizetikzpicture}
  \begin{autosizetikzpicture}{\linewidth}{}
    \genealogytree[]{
      insert{secondTree}
    }
  \end{autosizetikzpicture}
\end{document}
```